# BroadcastReceiver is not working after swiping app from recents list

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am working on internet calling app. In my app I am using to `BroadcastReceiver` to invoke call screen when app receives FCM data message with some specific keys. Normally is working fine, but if I swipe out my app from recent apps list it is not working. It seems like my `BroadcastReceiver` stops working after swiping app because all the FCM services are still and it receives FCM messages too and showing in logcat too.

I am registering my broadcast receiver in java code (**not** in manifest).

I used a service class to register broadcast receiver and also overrided `onTaskRemoved()` and used `AlarmManager` to keep service running but its not working too.

Why the `BroadcastReceiver` won't be fired and how to solve the problem?

Comment: Are you unregistering your receiver within onDestroy() method?

Comment: Is there any specific reason to register broadcast receiver in java code ?
because if register it in manifest all will work according to your requirement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am registering my broadcast receiver in java code (not in manifest).

That's the cause of your problem. When user swipes away your app from recents list, the process of your app is being destroyed. Thus, your `BroadcastReceiver` is being destroyed too.

Register your `BroadcastReceiver` in `AndroidManifest`, then `onReceive()` will be called regardless your app has a running process or no.

Comment: I tried this, it's working only in Lenovo p70, I also tested it in moto g3 but its not working or any other device

Comment: This worked, Thanks a ton. That was my mistake in code. Broadcast Receiver worked fine.